# Icefaces ace:dataTable lazy loading

Tags: datatable, loading, lazy-evaluation, icefaces, ace-editor

Is there anybody who have a little example of a lazy loading with ace:dataTable?.. 
I can't understand how to implement the load method of the class LazyDataModel.. and how to fetch data from a Database through this method..

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

***ace:dataTable*** has already a "built in" lazy loading mechanism in ICEFaces 
(at least for release 3.x and up).

No need to extend an ***AbstractList*** for this anymore.

All you need to do is add the ***lazy="true"*** to your tag, and make sure the "***value***" attribute points to a class that extends ***LazyDataModel***... you just need to implement the abstract
method there that accepts start page, page size, sorting & filtering arguments.

Also don't forget to use pagination and determine the size of the page ("rows" attribute).

Check: [ICEFaces docs Ver. 3 ace:dataTable](http://res.icesoft.org/docs/v3_latest/ace/tld/ace/dataTable.html)

Comment: Thanks @Nir M for the help i have gone through showcase example but i am not able to run the example could you please provide me the simple example of it if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's working sample

myDataTableLazy.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"
xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
xmlns:icecore="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/core"> 
<h:head> 
<title>DataTable</title>  
</h:head> 
<h:body> 


   <h:form>
            <ace:dataTable id="carTable"
                       value="#{myDataTableLazy.lazyModel}"
                       var="car"   
                       rows="5"                    
                       paginator="true" 
                       lazy="true" >

                <ace:column id="exp" rendered="false">
                    <ace:expansionToggler />
                </ace:column>

                <ace:column headerText="Id">
                    <ice:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
                </ace:column>
                <ace:column headerText="Name">
                    <ice:outputText value="#{car.name}" />
                </ace:column>

        </ace:dataTable>


        <h:commandButton id="invio" value="Invio"    actionListener="#{myDataTableLazy.cicla}"  > 
         </h:commandButton>  

    </h:form>
```

MyDataTableLazy

```
  package my;

  import java.io.Serializable;
  import java.util.List;

  import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
  import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
  import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped; 
  import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

  import org.icefaces.ace.model.table.LazyDataModel;
  import org.icefaces.samples.showcase.example.ace.dataTable.DataTableLazyLoading;
  import org.icefaces.samples.showcase.metadata.context.ComponentExampleImpl;

  @ManagedBean(name="myDataTableLazy")
  @SessionScoped
  public class MyDataTableLazy   implements Serializable { 

    private LazyDataModel<Car> lazyModel;

    @PostConstruct
      public void init() {
        lazyModel = new LazyCarDataModel();
      }

    public LazyDataModel<Car> getLazyModel() {
        return lazyModel;
    }

    public void setLazyModel(LazyDataModel<Car> lazyModel) {
        this.lazyModel = lazyModel;
    } 


     public void cicla(ActionEvent e)  { 

         List<Car> lista = (List<Car>) lazyModel.getWrappedData();

         for (Car car : lista) {
           System.out.println( car.getName() );
         } 

     }


  }
```

LazyCarDataModel

```
  package my;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Map;

  import org.icefaces.ace.model.table.LazyDataModel;
  import org.icefaces.ace.model.table.SortCriteria;

  public class LazyCarDataModel extends LazyDataModel<Car> {
    List<Car> carList;

    public LazyCarDataModel(){ 
        carList = new ArrayList<Car>();
        carList.add(new Car(1, "FiatLazy"));
        carList.add(new Car(2, "FerrariLazy"));
        carList.add(new Car(3, "PorscheLazy"));
        carList.add(new Car(4, "MaseratiLazy"));
        carList.add(new Car(5, "MercedesLazy"));
        carList.add(new Car(6, "BMWLazy"));
        carList.add(new Car(7, "ToyotaLazy"));
        carList.add(new Car(8, "FordLazy"));
        carList.add(new Car(9, "Alfa RomeoLazy"));
        carList.add(new Car(10, "SuzukiLazy"));
        carList.add(new Car(11, "RenaultLazy"));

        setRowCount(carList.size());
    }

    @Override
    public List<Car> load(int first, int pageSize, SortCriteria[] arg2, Map<String, String> arg3) {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList<Car>();

        int initial = first;

        for (int i = initial; i < initial + pageSize && i < carList.size(); i++) {
            list.add(carList.get(i));
        }

        return list;
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

ICEFaces ice/ace:DataTable underneath works with native Java Collections. Datatable accesses elements from your collection simply by invoking get(idx) method on your collection.

I suggest you should look into implementing lazy-loading/pagination on the lower level, like implementing your own [java.util.AbstractList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html).

Start by implementing its abstract get() method and debugging, to understand how icefaces datatable works, alternatively you can check out ice/ace:dataTable ice/ace:dataPaginator sources.

Answer (score 0):

Since IceFaces Ace is a copy/fork of PrimeFaces 2, PrimeFaces docs and samples may help. primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableLazy.jsf

Answer (score 0):

Pheraps it's quite off-topic, but to build the showcase examples:
go to http://www.icesoft.org/java/downloads/icefaces-downloads.jsf

you can select ICEfaces 4.x ICEfaces 3.x ICEfaces 1.x tab

download the ICEfaces-x.x.0-bin.zip file (you do the registration)

unzip and go to the folder you want compile, for example, in the command shell, go to
...\ICEfaces-3.3.0-bin.zip\ICEfaces-3.3.0-bin\icefaces\samples\showcase\showcase

launch the command (you must have maven):
**mvn package**

the you'll find showcase.war in

\ICEfaces-3.3.0-bin\ICEfaces-3.3.0-bin\icefaces\samples\showcase\showcase\target