# Need an examle of lazyloading in ace:datatable

Tags: jsf, lazy-loading, icefaces, icefaces-3, ace-datatable

i am using **icefaces 3**
and i took a look at the showcase for the **ace:datatable** lazyloading, but the example is very complicated, so can anyone please share with us an example of using lazyloading in ace:datatable to load data from the database not from collection, and how lazyloading works with search, thanks in advance.

Comment: you might want to check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/q/9638544/164299

Comment: Off topic but IceFaces is a fork of PrimeFaces, in case you don't know. http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1750